# How to highlight a Sprite type "image" with ExtJS 4.1?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4.1

I want to highlight a Ext.Draw.Sprite with type "image" dynamically. So I want to add either a colored background or a border or something like that.

I already tried the addCls-Method like that:

```
aElement.addCls('chosen-component');
```

with different styles like

```
.chosen-component { background: url(../images/stripes.svg) !important; }
```

or simply

```
.chosen-component { background: red; }
```

or

```
.chosen-component { border: 2px solid black; }
```

but unfortunately none of these approaches worked for me.

The HTML does change; is looks like

```
<image id="component_image-1275" xlink:href="image.svg" zIndex="0" src="image.svg" width="82" height="34" x="112.3115" y="163.9915" preserveAspectRatio="none" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" class="chosen-component"></image>
```

Also the setStyle-Method changes the HTML, but I can see no difference on the sprite.

I think it doesn't work, because that image-Tag is inside a svg-Tag, and I can't apply styles to it. But it must be possible somehow...

So, how can I add styles (like a Background-Image/-Color or a Border) to a Ext.Draw.Sprite?